# React Native snap carousel - Swipe direction or scroll enabling with restrictions

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I have implemented react native snap carousel. I have 4 forms in the carousel. The requirement is that if the form is valid then the user will be able to swipe to next but the user can swipe to left even if the form is invalid

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Hi @AnkushRishi I have created snap carousel, I need to swipe to right only if a variable is valid and I need to  swipe left even if the variable is true or not

Comment: Do you find any solution to this problem?